# Prototype - DOM Traversal with up()

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have the following structure:

```
<form>
    <div class="content">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="action">
        <p>Select <a class="select_all" href="?select=1" title="Select All">All</a></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am using Prototype's up() to traverse the DOM in order to find the `<form>` element in respect to the `a.select_all`. However the following doesn't work:

```
select_link.up('form'); // returns undefined
```

Yet, this does.

```
select_link.up().up().up(); // returns HTMLFormElement
```

Clearly this is an ancestor of `a.select_all`. The API Docs state `Element.up()` supports a CSSRule. What am I missing here?

Comment: The `up` function works exactly as advertised, you must be doing something else wrong. Any errors on the page?

Comment: Post the part where you set "select_link" to the `<a>` tag. (The fact that you can go "up().up().up()" suggests you've got the right thing, but still it'd be good to see more code.)

Comment: @Infinity. No other errors. I admit I may have something wrong, but maybe you can provide more suggestions.  @Pointy `var select_link = e.element();`. I have bound the function as an event listener. `e` comes in as the first argument. This is pretty standard stuff. As you said, it's odd that chaining them works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine by me: http://jsfiddle.net/f9HdB/

You can simply use Function#bind instead of Function#bindAsEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

Do you used a code like this:

```
var select_link = $$('.select_all').first()
```

to get the DOM-Object of the link?

Comment: `$$(base + ' .select_all', base + ' .select_none').invoke("observe", "click", toggle_checkboxes.bindAsEventListener(this));`